# Efficiently indexing an array by another array, without using a loop

Tags: arrays, matlab

I need something like `B(i,j) = f( A(i,j), i)`, where `A(i,j)` is an array of integers, `f(a,i)` is an array that specifies how an element of `a` in row `i` of array `A` should be converted.

What is an efficient way to do this in Matlab? I know I can do it by looping through `i`, but I want to make the code efficient since this step may be repeated a few million times.

Edit -- Here's the loop version:

```
B = zeros(iMax,jMax);
for i = 1:iMax
    B(i,:) = f(A(i,:),i)';
end
```

Comment: Show th eloopy version, then we can see if it can be improved. It seems the case for `sub2ind`, but your explanation is not very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sub2ind` in this case.

From the doc:

> sub2ind(matrixSize, rowSub, colSub) returns the linear index
>   equivalents to the row and column subscripts rowSub and colSub for a
>   matrix of size matrixSize.

Let's take an example:

```
n = 3300;
m = 5000;
A = randi(m,n,4); %randi(x1,y1,z1)
f = randi(10,m,n);%randi(x2,y2,z2) where  y2 >= x1 and z2 >= y1;

%For loop version
tic
B = zeros(size(A));
for ii = 1:size(A,1)
    B1(ii,:) = f(A(ii,:),ii);
end
toc

%Linear indexing version
tic
[s1,s2] = size(A);
sub     = [1:s1].'+zeros(1,s2);  %you can also use sub = repmat(1:s1,s2,1).'
s2i     = sub2ind(size(f),A,sub); %create the index according to the subscripts
B2      = f(s2i);
toc
```

result:

```
%for loop
%Elapsed time is 0.102647 seconds.
%sub2ind
%Elapsed time is 0.00155091 seconds.
```

To create `sub` I'm using the implicit expansion feature that recquired matlab 2016b or later.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, for my specific program, `sub2ind` is slightly slower, and I find the code much harder to understand. I guess using a loop is the best solution.

Comment: @JYeh, I'm a little bit supprised that the linear indexing method is slower, if I benchmark the 2 methods above, the sub2ind method is way faster, perhaps that something else in your code is not totally optimized ? I've edited my answer to add a timer.